# What is an "RRSP deduction limit" for?

Tags: canada, financial-literacy, contribution, rrsp, limits

I'm not asking what my limit is—I can see what is the dollar amount of my deduction limit.

Rather, I don't quite grasp what *is* an RRSP deduction limit for? Why is there a limit? A limit to what? What's being deducted?

Could someone please give me the For-Dummies explanation of the RRSP deduction limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the maximum amount of tax-free savings you can contribute towards your RRSP in a given year. Any excess contributions are not tax deductible.

Comment: So it's a cap on how much tax free money you can put away in a year?

Comment: Yes, that is right. It is 18% of your gross income or 20,000, whichever is lower (I think)

Comment: Hmm, well I don't think it's either of those, because my deduction limit this year is equal 100% of my gross.

Comment: Yes, you carry forward unused deduction limits from prior years.

Comment: FYI to all, that "20,000" mentioned is approximate and actually increases each year. For 2014 it was $24,270 and for 2015 it is $24,930. Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, it's not that "Any excess contributions are not tax deductible." but rather that the CRA doesn't let you make excess contributions, and you will face a penalty if you attempt to do so and surpass the extra $2000 wiggle room they give you.